# How can I use a list in tcl as an argument of multiple strings(not as one string)?

Tags: list, tcl

Specifically lets say i create a list with :

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(recv)} {incr i} {
    lappend bwList "videoBW_($i).tr"
    close $videoBW_($i)
}
```

and then i want to give that list as an argument of multiple files with

```
exec xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400  &
```

It will give me the error:
Warning:  cannot open file `videoBW_(0).tr videoBW_(1).tr videoBW_(2).tr'

Because tcl reads the whole list as one string instead of multiple strings.
Is there a way to read the list as multiple strings ?

EDIT :

The solution for tcl8.4 is the one Brian Fenton provided. 
but by changing set exec_call {xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400}
to set exec_call "xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400"

**Basically if you only add eval in front of exec it does the job .**

```
  eval exec xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400  &
```

Fot tcl 8.5 Bryan Oakley provided a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 8.5 and later:

```
exec xgraph {*}$bwList -geometry 800x400 &
```

In 8.4 and before:

```
eval exec xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400 &
# Or this more formally-correct version...
# eval [list exec xgraph] [lrange $bwList 0 end] [list -geometry 800x400 &]
```

As you can see, the 8.5 expansion syntax helps a lot, and that's particularly true as you go from simple experimentation to production code (e.g., if you're adding a label argument with spaces in to that command line; the expansion version will just handle it correctly, but with the old version you'll get into having to quote everything up properly, which you can see is *very* messy above).

Comment: Even though the other answers are also correct this is the most complete one and i am marking it so that other people can find it faster.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using tcl 8.5 or later you can do:

```
exec xgraph {*}$bwList -geometry 800x400  &
```

`{*}` is called the expansion operator. It expands lists into individual elements before the statement is executed.

See [section 5 of the Tcl man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) for the definitive explanation.

Comment: i am working on tcl 8.4 but this seems a more elegant solution for tcl8.5 or later so i voted up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you mean by "multiple strings". It would help me if you showed what the final call to xgraph should look like. I thought with xgraph that the files came at the end (i.e. after the -geometry 800x400)?

Anyway what might help is using **eval** instead of a direct call to **exec**.

```
set exec_call {xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400}
set caught [catch {eval exec $exec_call} result]
if { $caught } {
 #handle the error - it is stored in $result
} else {
 #handle the success
}
```

Comment: ok , the final call to xgraph should look like : exec xgraph videoBW_(0).tr videoBW_(1).tr -geometry 800x400  &
more specifically so you understand what i am saying  : 
exec xgraph "videoBW_(0).tr" "videoBW_(1).tr" -geometry 800x400  &

right now it is : exec xgraph "videoBW_(0).tr videoBW_(1).tr" -geometry 800x400  & 
which i don't want
Quote :
I thought with xgraph that the files came at the end (i.e. after the -geometry 800x400)?

It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: set exec_call {xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400} is wrong because it does not evaluate $bwList it should be: set exec_call "xgraph $bwList -geometry 800x400 . If you edit that in your answer it will be correct

Answer (score 2):

For Tcl 8.4 I'd do it like this:

```
set cmd [concat [list exec xgraph] $bwList]
lappend cmd -geometry 800x400
```

Comment: One of the canonical methods to ensure list-ness is: `set cmd [linsert $bwList 0 exec xgraph]; lappend cmd ...`

Comment: Correct. I prefer `[concat]` in this case because it looks more naturally with regard to the ordering of the elements of the resulting list. I mean, `exec xgraph` goes before `$bwList` in the code, so it looks less twisted compared to `[linsert]`.